# Problemas con Gradle en flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle

Estoy tratando de correr una app de flutter en mi teléfono, pero solo me sale el mismo error:

> "Your project path contains non-ASCII characters"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el gradle que tiene por defecto, ya intente cambiando minSdkVersion a 21 pero me arroja lo mismo y me marca como no valido Properties() y GradleException.
Disculpen que ponga solo imágenes, pero de lo contrario no me deja publicar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error está en la ruta donde se encuentra ubicado tu proyecto. Evita carpetas que contengan caracteres especiales y espacios en blanco (por precaución) en la ruta. Una opción sería el trabajar con una carpeta en el disco local C y así te aseguras de que la app se ejecute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mensaje de error "Your project path contains non-ASCII characters".
indica:

> La ruta de su proyecto contiene caracteres que no son ASCII.

Si revisas la ruta de tu proyecto, tienes un carácter que está provocando el problema,

[image: Android Studio Jorgesys]

en este caso te sugiero evites caracteres acentuados en donde contengas tus proyectos para Android Studio.